# JavaFX scene loading slow due to Fontawesome icons

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, font-awesome, scenebuilder

- I am using jdk1.8.0_151 and net beans 8.2 and Scene builder 8.4.1.
  While I use font awesome Icon in my scene. The scene is loading very
  slow(5-6 seconds delay) for the first time. While I remove those
  fontawesome icon view from layout the scene is loading instantly.
  Using FontAwesome 8.9.

```
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextArea?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" style="-fx-background-color: #CBE32D;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication1.FXMLTextsDocumentController">
   <children>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="351.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="145.0" text="Texts Example" />
      <Button fx:id="mainButton" layoutX="648.0" layoutY="31.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBackToMainButton" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="133.0" text="Back To Main" />
      <Text fx:id="text1" fontSmoothingType="LCD" layoutX="66.0" layoutY="69.0" onMouseClicked="#handleText1" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" style="-fx-fill: #7E8F7C;" text="This is example text!" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="144.9999988079071">
         <font>
            <Font name="Calibri Light" size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <TextField fx:id="textFieldName" layoutX="275.0" layoutY="53.0" onKeyReleased="#handleTextField" promptText="Type Name" />
      <Label fx:id="textLabelName1" layoutX="449.0" layoutY="57.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="274.0" textFill="#f50303" />
      <JFXTextField fx:id="JFXNumberTextField" layoutX="71.0" layoutY="116.0" promptText="Type number" />
      <TextArea fx:id="textAreaAddress" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="94.0" onKeyTyped="#handleTextAreaAddress" prefHeight="87.0" prefWidth="263.0" promptText="Enter Address" />
      <JFXTextArea fx:id="JFXTextAreaAddress" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="198.0" onKeyReleased="#handleJFXTextAreaAddress" prefHeight="87.0" prefWidth="285.0" promptText="Enter Comment..." />
      <JFXTextField fx:id="JFXTextFieldSearchName" layoutX="247.0" layoutY="341.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="285.0" promptText="Search Name..." />
      <Button fx:id="iconStyleButton" layoutX="87.0" layoutY="367.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleIconStyleButton" text="Icon Style" />
      <FontAwesomeIconView fx:id="fABook2" glyphName="BOOK" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="269.0" size="36" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Have you tried using smaller versions of the icons that will load faster? What about preloading the icons into memory before displaying the scene, perhaps at application launch? I'm not familiar with font-awesome, but I doubt the problem is unique to it.

Comment: loaded fast for me.

Comment: @Airhead I have tried with smaller font size as well but of no use.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson how? can please explain?

Comment: There is nothing to explain. I created a project,  copied your `FXML`, and added the supporting libraries. I then ran the code. It was a near instant start for me. I didn't have any code in my `@FXML` methods, but I did create the methods.

Comment: Strange!!! :(  .

Comment: Could be different OS or hardware...

Comment: mine Windows 8.1 core i5

Comment: Windows 10 - i5 - same version of Netbeans, SceneBuilder, and JDK.